# MS SQL Server backup to remote PC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, active-directory

Currently, I am creating a backup of my database on database server filesystem.
Following is the code, that I am using to achieve this using SMO namespace:

```
backup.Devices.AddDevice(filePath, SMO.DeviceType.File);
backup.BackupSetName = fileName;
backup.BackupSetDescription = fileDescription;
backup.Initialize = false;
backup.SqlBackup(server);
backup.Wait();
```

I want to be able to create backup on remote PC under Active Directory (Domain).

Suppose, I have PC **"A"** as IIS server and PC **"B"** as Database Server. And an active directory folder address as **"ww007.somename.net\folder"**.
Is it possible to get backup file as a file stream back to PC **A** from PC **B**? So that I can save that file to active directory using C#.
OR
Is it possible to include **ww007.somename.net\folder** in above code and achieve same results through database server.

Comment: It is possible to do from the sql-server. But the way I managed to do it requires a user to be logged in on the server which has rights in the destination folder. I can supply that as an answer if it fills your needs. If you cant have a user logged in it wont work.

Comment: @Sourcery, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

This script makes a backup of all the databases on the server to a remote server. You can modify it to just backup certain databases as you see fit.

So as long as you have rights to the destination folder you can do the backup to other server.

1. Make sure that the logged in user on the SQL-server has rights to the destination folder.
2. Mount or connect to the share on the destination server.
3. Modify the code below to your server and conditions, and either run it in the console or with a osql command.

   DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
   DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files
   DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup
   DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 
   SET @path = '\\10.your.server.ip\share\whatever_extra_folder\'
   SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
   DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT name 
   FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
   WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
   OPEN db_cursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'
      BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
   END
   CLOSE db_cursor
   DEALLOCATE db_cursor

I run if from the Microsoft Task Scheduler (run only when user is logged in) with a cmd file containing this row:

```
osql -E -Syour_sql_server_name -n -iF:\folder\sql_file_with_abvove_code.sql -oF:\folder\a_log_file.txt
```

It works like a charm for me taking backups to remote server. I did not make the above code, just modified it and do not take credit for it. Hope it works for you.

Comment: "BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName" is enough, if we have control over database server(write permissions/service logOn). My problem, i donot have control over database server. That is the reason, i wanted to solve this problem from WebServer side (if it is possible).

Comment: Could you give permission on the file server for the SQL-SERVER? So in permission handling you need to find and give rights to the computer instead of the user. Then it might work to run the command form inside SQL without having to map/connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a related code I would like to keep in stackoverflow. This code is used to reads the backup file, since backups are normally stored on the SQL server. This is a simple way to transfer backups to remote clients over SQL 1433 port. Hope it helps others.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\YourServer;Database=ValidDatabase;User Id=User;Password = Password;");
        SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\MSSQL\Backup\DbBackup.bak', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Contents";
        con.Open();
        command.BeginExecuteReader(callback, command,
                CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.EndExecuteReader(ar);
        bool res = reader.Read();
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(reader.GetStream(0)))
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\temp\RemoteDbBackupbak.bak");
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                int index = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((index = br.Read(buffer, 0, 8192)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```